# avoiding zombie processes with Ruby's Net::SSH gem when connection fails

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems

I have an application that does something like this using Ruby's Net::SSH gem:

```
key = '/home/creede/.ssh/secret.pem'
conn = nil
begin
    conn = Net::SSH::start('example.com','creede',:timeout=>60,:keys=>[key])
rescue
    begin
        conn = Net::SSH::start('example.com','root',:timeout=>60,:keys=>[key])
    rescue Exception => e
        puts "Can't connect to example.com: #{e.to_s}"
        if not conn.nil?
            if not conn.closed?
                conn.close
            end
        end
    end
end
issue = conn.exec!('cat /etc/issue')
conn.close
```

All well and good when we connect to the server the first time. However if the server needs to be logged into as root because the first try at connecting fails, the first attempted ssh process turns into a zombie. So does the second one if connecting as root fails.

These zombies disappear when the parent process finishes, but I'd like to figure out how (if possible) to get rid of the zombies as soon as we know the connection fails.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, other than to let the program end and then all the zombies go away.